# Когда Дух удаляет свежие вопросы?

Tags: поддержка, дух-сообщества, удаление-вопросов

[Как подсчитать количество слов в строке?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/476982/178988)

Вопрос удалён Духом Сообщества через 12 часов после того, как был задан.
Насколько я помню, в описании речь шла о полугоде или годе в зависимости от рейтинга.
По какой причине вопросы могут удаляться так быстро?

PS: Да и вообще, не вижу причин удалять этот вопрос.

Comment: Посмотрите в историю — кто там голосовал за удаление?

Comment: @NickVolynkin там нет голосов за удаление. удалил именно бот.

Comment: @NickVolynkin: на спам или оскорбление тоже не тянет?

Comment: @NickVolynkin, во-первых, явно нет - просто некачественный вопрос. Во-вторых, у него рейтинг -2, а спам/оскорбление дали бы -5. К тому же, вопрос не скрыт - показывается оригинальный текст - со спамом не так.

Comment: Переименовать его в Жнеца Вопросов.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Предполагаю, что был удалён *автор* вопроса (либо модератором, либо по собственной инициативе). Когда удаляется пользователь, их посты с **отрицательным** рейтингом удаляются Духом (прочие остаются).